# How to limit the width of a DIV

Tags: html, css

The div with class `main` should take only 30%
in the left side of my page but it takes the full width instead. I tried to specify width but
it's not working.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="main">
          <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="content-section">
                <h3>Latest Covid Info</h3>
                <p class='text-muted'>You can put any information here you'd like.
                  <ul class="list-group">
                    <div>
                      <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Total Cases</li>
                      <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Total Deaths</li>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div>
                      <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Total Population</li>
                      <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Vaccinated People Count</li>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div>
                      <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Announcements</li>
                      <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Calendars</li>
                      <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">etc</li>
                    </div>
                  </ul>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Making a snippet which shows the problem will help us find it. Keep it simple though, just enough CSS/HTML plus whatever libraries you are using to make sure it shows the problem. See [link]https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The div "main" has no style applied to it, so it will expand to fit the width of the browser window. The next child div has `class="col-md-4"` but you are no linking a stylesheet so it will have no effect (same for the next child div as well)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the div width with CSS:

```
.main {
  width: 30%;
}
```

```css
.main {
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
      <div class="main">
          <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="content-section">
                <h3>Latest Covid Info</h3>
                <p class='text-muted'>You can put any information here you'd like.</p>
                  <ul class="list-group">
                    <div>
                      <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Total Cases</li>
                      <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Total Deaths</li>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div>
                      <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Total Population</li>
                      <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Vaccinated People Count</li>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div>
                      <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Announcements</li>
                      <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Calendars</li>
                      <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">etc</li>
                    </div>
                  </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```